# Executing SP inside while loop works only first time

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2012, I have a script that call a stored procedure multiple times.. The loop will be executed as many times as the number of records in [ResultHeader] table.

```
 EXEC [AS400].tp_SelectChildItems @Pgm, @Grp, @Pgmgrpseq, 
                       null, null, null, null, null, @ItemSelection, null,
                       null, null, null, null,
```

Note: This SP has a `table variable` inside

I have a comma separated list of SelectedCostPageList. For each value in this list, the loop is executed once.

I am observing a weird behavior.  When I invoke the sp from the script, only for the first time the sp is returning proper records.. On subsequent calls the stored procedure is returning no records. Very odd…. When I change the order of comma separated string, only for the first iteration the sp is returing records.. other times no records.

Any guess what will be the reason?

```
       DECLARE @SelectedCostPageList VARCHAR(MAX)

       SET @SelectedCostPageList = (SELECT (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), A.PGM + '-'+A.GRP+'-'+A.PGMGRPSEQ) + ', ' AS [text()]
       FROM dbo.[ResultHeader] A
       WHERE UserId = 'U25703'
       FOR XML PATH('')) AS CostPages) ResultHeader

       PRINT @SelectedCostPageList


       DECLARE @pos INT
       DECLARE @len INT
       set @pos = 0
       set @len = 0

              DELETE FROM ResultItems

       WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @SelectedCostPageList, @pos+1)>0
       BEGIN

              set @len = CHARINDEX(',', @SelectedCostPageList, @pos+1) - @pos
              DECLARE @SelectedCostPage VARCHAR(10)
              set @SelectedCostPage = SUBSTRING(@SelectedCostPageList, @pos, @len)
              set @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @SelectedCostPageList, @pos+@len) +1
              PRINT @SelectedCostPage



              DECLARE @Pgm AS VARCHAR (10);
              DECLARE @Grp AS VARCHAR (10);
              DECLARE @Pgmgrpseq AS VARCHAR (10);



              SELECT @Pgm = (SELECT VALUE
              FROM [AS400].[tf_SelectSplitString] (@SelectedCostPage, '-')
              WHERE POSITION = 1);
              PRINT @Pgm
              SELECT @Grp = (SELECT VALUE
              FROM [AS400].[tf_SelectSplitString] (@SelectedCostPage, '-')
              WHERE POSITION = 2);
              PRINT @Grp
              SELECT @Pgmgrpseq = (SELECT VALUE
              FROM [AS400].[tf_SelectSplitString] (@SelectedCostPage, '-')
              WHERE POSITION = 3);
              PRINT @Pgmgrpseq

              Declare @ItemSelection as varchar(4000)
              set @ItemSelection ='1116102540,1116102541';
              print @ItemSelection

              print 'HAI'
              print @Pgmgrpseq

                           EXEC [AS400].tp_SelectChildItems
                           @Pgm, @Grp, @Pgmgrpseq, 
                           null, null, null, 
                           null, null, @ItemSelection, null,
                           null, null, null, null, 
                           null, null, null, 1, 'U25703'



                           END

                           SELECT * FROM ResultItems
                           WHERE UserId = 'U25703'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess, it would be because you are using `', '` (comma followed by a space) as a list separator, but the code is just looking for a comma.  You would then have a leading space on a string value, which, presumably, would not then match whatever needs to be matched.

The first works, because you initialize the list string with a comma without a space.

Perhaps more importantly, I find the approach of stuffing things into a string to loop over them to be, shall I say, very 1980s.  You could use a cursor (not my favorite approach) or a temporary table.  When I want to do loops over such data, I sometimes structure them as follows:

```
declare @looptable table (rownum int identity(1, 1), . . . );
insert into @looptable . . .;
declare @tot int;
select @tot = count(*) from @looptable;
declare @i int = 1;
while (@i <= tot)
begin
    -- something here with "where rownum = @i"
end;
```

The idea of stuffing values into a string just to write more code to parse them out seems like a waste of programming effort.  In addition, this can cause problems because of the conversion of types into character formats and the obscene ways that `for path xml` handles characters such as `'<'` and `'>'`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I will try.... And a great piece of advise too.... Thanks